# How to change the font size of the Visual Studio 2017 'Find and Replace' control?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Note that this is NOT the dialog box, but the box that opens up in the top right corner of the file window.

[image]

I've checked the following without finding an answer.  Right now the text is very tiny and difficult to make out!

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139eef4h.aspx
   : Couldn't find any instructions to adjust the font size.
2. Tools in Menu -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors
   : Couldn't find the 'Find and Replace' control.

Enlarging the font of the editor does make the font larger, but it doesn't work because the size of the editor font becomes huge before the control's font is readable.

Comment: Did you find an answer? I find in 2019 everything is reasonable size except that Find dialog is about 5 pixels smaller than everything else.

Comment: No I did not find a solution to this. Nice to know others have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So your best option might be to go into settings and change window.zoomLevel to 1. This will zoom in the window and should give you the effect your looking for. I don't believe you can change menu fontSize etc.

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl, use mouse scroll to increase the overall size of text area and find and replace window. Now go to tool->options->font to set default size for text area only.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the show but figured I'd post my solution for other people late to finding this post.

I still don't think there are any specific settings for things like Find/Replace Font Size, however, you can adjust the size of the UI independently from the editor (the code text).

Use `Ctrl+Plus` and `Ctrl+Minus` to zoom the interface.
The editor's code font can be adjusted by holding ctrl and spinning the mouse wheel.
`Ctrl+Wheeldown` decreases the text size while `Ctrl+Wheelup` increases it.

If these hotkeys don't work, use `Ctrl+Shift+p` to bring up the Command Palette. Search for `zoom`.
You'll see options to set the hotkeys for both `View: Zoom In/Zoom Out` and `Editor Font: Zoom In/Zoom Out`.