Increase Visual Studio 2022 Find and Replace dialog font size
Are there any keyboard shortcuts to set font size of the "Find and Replace" dialog of the text editor?

I probably reduced the font size inadvertently and I am not able to locate any way in the "Tools>Options>Fonts and Colors" section to increase or restore it. I have increased the font size of every item there from 9 to 10. This increased fonts in all sorts of other texts except the "Find and Replace" window...
I checked "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75187127/visual-studio-2022-font-size-is-way-too-small-in-the-tooltips-how-to-increase-t" and the suggestions there havn't worked.

So, if I understand correctly, you're saying that after adjusting the font size, there's no change in the Find and Replace window? Are you looking to apply the same size adjustment to the "Find" window as well?

@DennisLi - yes there is no change after increasing practically every font size setting under the toolls>options>Find and Replace. and yes : Find window font also is too small + its shared by Find and Replace interface

Maybe you can try directly adjusting the size by using CTRL + scroll wheel to resize it to your preference before using the search function. I tried it. In this case, the display of the code and the search box will become larger simultaneously.

@Dennis Li - wow I cant believe this. I did try CRTL+scroll wheel but ONLY inside the find and replace window - and it just scrolls the code without changing any font.
BUT CRTL+scroll directly on the code window WORKS ! so thanks a lot ! I dont know why I assumed trying inside Find window is the same - feel stupid :)
I guess that explains how I inadvertently reduced the Find window font - the code font would also have reduced which I was able to increase from Tools>Options>Fonts...
Please post as answer and I will accept it.

This is actually the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70373775/12096922

I think you can try directly adjusting the size by using CTRL + scroll wheel to resize it to your preference directly on the code window. And I have already tested this way and found that you can directly enlarge the font size of the "Search Window" and "Code Window".

You can't really change the font size separately in the "Search and Replace" window. Also, there's no need to change the whole Visual Studio window size.
Instead, you need to adjust the font for the environment and text editor separately.
Here are my recommendations:

Use Segoe UI 10 or 11 as the environment font (Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors > Environment). Segoe UI font 9 or 10 will be installed in the "Search and Replace" window.
Choose Cascadia Code 14 as the text editor font (Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors > Text Editor).

